# Need to animate the circle border clock wise

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I need to rotate the dashed stroke circle clock wise, currently its rotation "anti clock wise". I think it can we done using PATH, but don't know how i can create it,

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 500 500" >
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="167" stroke-dasharray="2,4" stroke-width="2"  stroke="red" fill="white" stroke-linecap="round" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="167" stroke-dasharray="1200,1200" stroke-width="3" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="white" fill="none" >
       <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="1200" dur="4s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Here is link,

https://jsfiddle.net/y492v144/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your answer already in stackoverflow please check it jquery tag

Comment: @DivyeshChothani : i dont think there 's any  which uses `svg` `css3` `htm5` .

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply, yes, i know, it is in jquery post, but i need some modification, and different result so i added new post... Thanks both..:)

Answer (score 1):

check out this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/y492v144/1/)

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 500 500" >
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="167" stroke-dasharray="2,4" stroke-width="2"  stroke="red" fill="white" stroke-linecap="round" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="167" stroke-dasharray="1200,1200" stroke-width="3" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="white" fill="none" >
       <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="-1200" dur="4s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Just give `to` coordinate a `negative value`

Comment: Perfect, thanks, can we start the circle from the top...?